# Cannot display data from API request in views

Tags: api, express, view, ejs, display

I am brand new to Express and Node.js, trying to build server-rendered app which will display some data from API.

This is my code

app.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var apiKey = '****************************';
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('viewEngine', 'ejs');

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://api.somethingsomething.com/content/search/v1?',
  headers: {
    'X-Api-Key': `${apiKey}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: {
    'queryString': 'pigs',
    'resultContext' : {
         'aspects' :['title','lifecycle','location','summary','editorial' ]
        }
      },
      json: true
    }

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var info = JSON.stringify(body);
      console.log(info);
      res.render('index', { results: info}); // this does not render anything 
    }
  })
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
})
```

index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="searchResults">
        <%= results %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It does not render index.ejs and cannot display data.
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
I tried googling it, but no luck. Any help will be appreciated; Thank you

Answer (score 0):

problem was simple app.set('viewEngine', 'ejs'); was wrong, should be pp.set('view engine', 'ejs');